# Form #states API by content type

Tags: 8, forms, hooks, ajax

I have a content type `A`. In this content type, i have paragraph (between 0 to n) with 2 fields.

First field is content type select (A, B and C).

Second field is based on the first field, only need to show off if the content type selected is B or C (more than that, i need to `entityQuery` to see if B or C is a child of A).

Can i use `form states API` to alter the form and only display the second field based on the type selected on the first field ? And also `Ajax` to reload the content of it ? Do you see an other way ?

Comment: Do you know https://www.drupal.org/project/dynamic_entity_reference ? Sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes i know the module but he is not working for what i want to do.